# How to remove mouse over cursor effect of PDF link annotation using itextsharp / iText?

Tags: c#, itext

I have hard time to remove link annotations with it's text styles from pdf.

However I was able to replace link action using following code.

```
Annots = PageDictionary.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
if ((Annots == null) || (Annots.Length == 0))
{
  continue;
}
foreach (PdfObject A in Annots.ArrayList)
{
    PdfDictionary AnnotationDictionary = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(A);

    if (!AnnotationDictionary.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE).Equals(PdfName.LINK))
    {
      continue;
    }
    if (AnnotationDictionary.Get(PdfName.A) == null)
    {
        continue;
    }

    PdfDictionary AnnotationAction =(PdfDictionary)AnnotationDictionary.GetAsDict(PdfName.A);
    if (AnnotationAction.Get(PdfName.S).Equals(PdfName.URI))
    {
        AnnotationAction.Remove(PdfName.S);
        AnnotationAction.Remove(PdfName.URI);
        AnnotationAction.Put(PdfName.S, PdfName.GOTO);
    }
}
```

But still mouse over/click effects and link underline remain the same.

How can I remove all link text styles and mouse actions of annotation?

Comment: Stuff like mouse appearance over an annotation is not specified by the pdf specification. Thus, this is up for the pdf viewer to decide. Creating link-like mouse appearances looks like a natural choice for a pdf viewer when confronted with a link annotation.

Comment: The link annotation only defines the area which shall be an active link. The link *text* is part of the page content, so you have to edit the page content to change that appearance which is clearly non-trivial.

Comment: That being said, there are pdf viewers which look through the page content, search for url-like text, make that text clickable (if it was not in a link annotation area), and change its appearance. This is highly viewer dependent.

Comment: Hi, mkl, thanks for your comments regarding this. My other concern is that I can easily modify the same pdf link using PDF Writer provided by Adobe, So how they identifying each object separately like link text, mouse action, and text underline. So if there is a way to do this, can't we do it programmatically using an opensource library like iText.?

Comment: Content text editing in PDFs is highly non-trivial and not that well supported in open PDF libraries. Recognizing underlines (and not mistaking underlines for other lines like separators or table borders or vice versa) is non-trivial, too. Mouse effects sound like something done in JavaScript and the JavaScript object model for PDF processors is *not* specified in the PDF specification. I would assume that Adobe is fairly good in manipulating these things if done by their software or similar to that but it likely can be easily misled.

Answer (score 0):

Apply this i hope so it will work

```
//  Get the current page
    PageDictionary = R.GetPageN(i);

    //Get all of the annotations for the current page
    Annots = PageDictionary.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);

    foreach (PdfObject A in Annots.ArrayList)
    {
    //code to check the annotation 

    //remove the annotation
    Annots.Remove(int idx);

    }
```

Comment: This is not worked for me, even it is not removing my annotation list. I can replace my annotation action. But my problem is i cannot find a way to remove the style of specific annotation.